# jQuery error with script referencing another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to debug an error on this site: www.naijastories.com.

When I click on the 'Donate' link on [this page](http://www.naijastories.com/2014/11/donate-page/), nothing happens, even though a pop-up is supposed to appear.

Digging deeper and using the IE developer function, I see that the following error is reported:

`"Object doesn't support property or method 'prompt'"`

The object in this case is the jQuery object, and the error occurs in the /wp-content/plugins/cubepoints/modules/donate/donate.js file.

The line with the error is

`var $imp = jQuery.prompt(donatePrompt);`

`prompt` is the missing property.

This is strange, because the prompt property is set in the first line of another js file - /wp-content/plugins/cubepoints/modules/donate/jquery.impromptu.4.0.min.js - which is loaded just before the donate.js file is loaded.

Is the problem that the donate.js file is not seeing what has been done in the jquery.impromptu.4.0.min.js file?

How do I find out why the jQuery global is not being properly populated with the prompt property?

Comment: Where's the donate link?

Comment: Sorry about that, @arao6. I realised that the link only showed up in authenticated pages, so I've created a special page with the link. I've edited the original post to include a link to the page.

Comment: I get "You must be logged in to make a transfer!" when clicking the donate link, no error in console.

Comment: This is quite bizarre. @arao6. You are getting the exact message that you should be getting, which means that this could be a client error. Can you tell me your client setup? I've tried deleting my cache and cookies, but that makes no difference. I've tried this on different browsers, and I get the same error. I've forced a cache refresh of the script from the server - same issue. I'd really love to know what you've done at your own end to resolve the issue.

Comment: Just a note: I tried this in Chrome and got 9 javascript errors before I even clicked on donate. You might want to look at those first to make sure they aren't causing the problem.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. However, I suspect that your problem is with the jquery-impromptu plugin. Try updating it to the latest version: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/jquery-impromptu.js

Comment: Thanks, @arao6. I updated the js file, but the error still persisted.

Comment: I don't think it updated. Try typing in `$.prompt` on console, which doesn't exist on your page, but `jQuery.prompt` does. And `jQuery.prompt` only exists in Chrome, but does not exist in IE, which hints that there's a conflict somewhere with the Impromptu plugin and something else and it's browser-specific. You need to be able to type `$.prompt` into console and see the function instead of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prompt' of undefined`, which I see on your page but not http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/ Note that this seems to happen in IE and not the other browsers.

Comment: @arao6, I found the problem - it was an outdated script in an ad which was conflicting with the site's script. Can you make a post so that I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: Those bugs are hard to track down. Glad you found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jQuery.prompt` only exists in Chrome, but  not in IE, which hints that there's a conflict somewhere with the Impromptu plugin and something else and it's browser-specific. You need to be able to type `$.prompt` into console and see the function instead of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prompt' of undefined`, which I see on your page but not http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu. Note that this seems to happen in IE and not the other browsers.